# Can we update a radock without updating the full radock zone..?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik

Can a ajax update panel be placed inside a Radock control? I don't need to update the complete radock zone , only the dock need to be updated..Can somebody help me with this matter..?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on demos.telerik.com with RadDocks containing UpdatePanel controls. Here is a link to it: "[My Portal demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dock/examples/myportal/defaultcs.aspx)". For example if you add the "ExchangeRates.ascx" dock to the page and press the "Calculate Rate" button, only this dock will be updated.

Comment: In all the examples, only the contents inside <telerik:RadDock> can be updated.But my requirement is to update the whole <telerik:RadDock> since my need is to update the skin of the dock to the skin of the dock zone to which I have dragged the dock..I read in some site that only <telerik:RadDock> controls can occur inside <telerik:RadDockZone>..In that case I can't put a <updatePanel> inside <telerik:RadDockZone> and then a <telerik:RadDock> inside the <updatePanel>.